# Super initialization of UIView causes the following crash: Fatal signal EXC_SOFTWARE / SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to initialize a subclass of `UIView`.

I'm seeing the following exception that's being thrown:

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1853e7048 __abort_with_payload + 8
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1853e1bd8 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 96
2 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1853e1b74 abort_with_reason + 32
3 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b1be8c _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 108
4 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b1bde4 _objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 40
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b1a610 _collecting_in_critical() + 372
6 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b19e94 cache_collect + 68
7 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b1a220 cache_fill + 268
8 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b25894 lookUpImpOrForward + 564
9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b25628 lookUpImpOrNil + 8
10 libobjc.A.dylib 0x184b1a8c4 class_getMethodImplementation + 36
11 UIKit 0x18f171c78 +[UIView(Internal) _registerClassForIdiomInitializationIfNeccessary] + 64
12 UIKit 0x18ee8e3f4 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 376
13 UIKit 0x18ee8e208 -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 144
14 An App 0x104ca0404 -[myCustomView initWithFrame:] (myCustomView.m:20)
```

The offending line from the stack trace is my initialization function for myCustomView: `self = [super initWithFrame:frame]`

context code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
 // do some processing
}
return self;
```

I can't reproduce the issue locally but I've gotten reports of this issue. Why would `self = [super initWithFrame:frame]` cause a crash? My understanding is super will at worst be nil so we'd return nil. Is there some internal bug with initWithFrame for UIViews?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: nah never figured it out